# What is the best way to debug Adobe Flex CSS?

Tags: css, apache-flex, debugging

I'm thinking this whole edit, compile, run, and pray cycle isn't very efficient.  I have a set of compiled css files and yesterday it was working, and today many the CSS rules are being ignored.  I guess there isn't a FireBug for Flex, but there has to a better way to get to the root of these kinds of issues.

Comment: try to load and apply the css dynamic and not compile it. Just a thought...

Comment: Linking the CSS directly produced a lot of useful error informaiton, however when I turned those working CSS style sheets into pre-compiled CSS they stopped working.  Pre-compiled and regular CSS style sheets work differently apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest FlexSpy http://code.google.com/p/fxspy/ it's not a surefire answer to the question but I know it helps those whose concentration is styling here pretty often (also allows you to tweak things and see the result live before going back and setting it as a style).  The style manager is very forgiving in terms of errors so it doesn't tend to tell you very often when things fail it just sits silently.

Comment: I'm trying it yet it doesn't seem to report the application of the color style on a spark label.  I was trying to figure out why my CSS wasn't applying the color and FlexSpy did not help.  Eventually I figured it out but I still need a good debugging tool.